# What is the difference between incrementing an array pointer and accessing a pointer's array via its index?

Tags: c, pointers

I have some code to read a file byte by byte, and store the data in blocks. I have the blocks separated via dynamically allocated memory. Here is my code:

```
  int ch = NULL;
  while (ch != EOF) {
    //Read 16-byte blocks of data from a text file or until the EOF flag is found
    for (size_t i = 0; i < UINT16_MAX && stream && ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF); ++i) {
      //(void)printf("%c", ch);
      *blocks += (char)abs(ch);
    }

    //Increase allocated memory blocks if the previous has been filled 
    if (ch != EOF) {
      uint32_t* tempMem = realloc(blocks, ++size * sizeof(uint32_t));
      if (tempMem == NULL) {
        free(blocks);
        (void)printf("Error: could not allocate memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      blocks = tempMem;
      *(++blocks) = 0; //zero-initialize new memory location
    }
  }
```

With this code, I get a corrupted heap address breakpoint, but if I change the memory access method, like so:

```
  int ch = NULL;
  while (ch != EOF) {
    //Read 16-byte blocks of data from a text file or until the EOF flag is found
    for (size_t i = 0; i < UINT16_MAX && stream && ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF); ++i) {
      //(void)printf("%c", ch);
      blocks[size - 1] += (char)abs(ch);
    }

    //Increase allocated memory blocks if the previous has been filled 
    if (ch != EOF) {
      uint32_t* tempMem = realloc(blocks, ++size * sizeof(uint32_t));
      if (tempMem == NULL) {
        free(blocks);
        (void)printf("Error: could not allocate memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      blocks = tempMem;
      blocks[size - 1] = 0;
    }
  }
```

I get no errors and the code runs fine (albeit with logic errors, but this is an educational project anyways). How come doing `array[++index]` works fine, but `*(++pointer_to_an_array)` breaks everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++blocks` changes `blocks`, after which it is no longer the address of the start of the allocated memory, so it is not the correct address to pass to `free` or `realloc`.